# Interactive visualization interface using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, visualization, interactive

I created a tower of Hanoi code using python. Now, I want to visualize the steps after running the code. For example, when my code prints 'Move from A to C', one disc will move from Stack A to Stack C. Then next maybe B to C. I want to visualize the steps using some python code. I know it can be done using R shiny, but I have to do it using python only. Does anyone have any idea what are the possible options for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the interactive part you have a few tools available. [Bowtie](https://github.com/jwkvam/bowtie) and [Dash](https://github.com/plotly/dash) are tools like Shiny for Python (disclaimer I wrote Bowtie). You could also do this with Jupyter Notebooks using [widgets](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets).

For the visualization, the standard tool is matplotlib.